# Do we still have to make a fat jar for submitting jobs in Spark 2.0.0?

Tags: apache-spark, jar, uberjar

In the Spark 2.0.0's release [note](https://spark.apache.org/releases/spark-release-2-0-0.html), it says that:

> Spark 2.0 no longer requires a fat assembly jar for production deployment.

- Does this mean that we do not need to make a fat jar anymore for submitting jobs ?
- If yes, how ? Thus the documentation [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html) isn't up-to-date.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Does this mean that we do not need to make a fat jar anymore for
>   submitting jobs ?

Sadly, no. You still have to create an uber JARs for Sparks deployment.

The title from the release notes is *very* misleading. The actual meaning is that Spark itself as a dependency is no longer compiled into an uber JAR, but acts like a normal application JAR with dependencies. You can see this in more detail @ [`SPARK-11157`](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-11157) which is called "Allow Spark to be built without assemblies", and read the paper called ["Replacing the Spark Assembly with good old
jars"](https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/attachment/12767129/no-assemblies.pdf) which describes the pros and cons of deploying Spark not as several huge JARs (Core, Streaming, SQL, etc..) but as a several relatively regular sized JARs containing the code and a `lib/` directory with all the related dependencies.

If you really want the details, [this pull request](https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/11591) touches several key parts.

Comment: I read you answer like 10 times. I also read links you provided. Can you clearly specify a reason why I must create fat jar? What if I won't, what are potential problems with just specifying a provided scope for all spark dependencies?

Comment: @MaxNevermind If you don't, and ship only your compiled code, who will provide the third party dependencies? At runtime, your app will blow up with a `ClassNotFoundException`.

Comment: I asked a wrong question. What if I make a fat jar but specify a provided scope for all spark dependencies because they are provided by the environment anyway? So, third party dependencies that my app uses but Spark doesn't will be packed in a fat jar.

Comment: Or maybe I understand the whole situation incorrectly. Is it required that Spark should be packaged as a dependency in a fat jar or not? That's a question I really try to find an answer to.